# raven - sentry + django = No servers configured, and sentry not installed. Cannot send message

Tags: sentry, raven

I have a sentry server that works ok.

```
raven test <dnstoserver> -> Sending a test message... success!
```

I have a dev machine with django 1.3 and raven 1.93.
In the django project I have this:

setting.py:

```
SENTRY_KEY=<secretkey>
SENTRY_DNS=<dnstoserver>

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'bar',
    'foo',
    'raven.contrib.django',
)

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'root': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'handlers': ['sentry'],
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'raven': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console', 'sentry'],
            'propagate': False,
        },        
    },
}
```

Mind the absence of 'sentry' in the installed_apps. This is intentionally, since sentry is the server and should not be on a client!

views.py (in a view):

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("raven")
logger.error("test")
```

When I run the view I get on the console:

```
No servers configured, and sentry not installed. Cannot send message
```

Why, and how to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Were you really setting `SENTRY_DNS` or `SENTRY_DSN`?

When you set `SENTRY_DSN` the instantiation of the major config variables happens automatically (including `SENTRY_SERVERS`, `SENTRY_PUBLIC_KEY`, `SENTRY_SECRET_KEY`, and `SENTRY_PROJECT`)

Comment: Mmm, maybe the problem was that typo ;) Thanks. I have another issue where anything send to the non default project is silently discarded. Will make issue in github.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the construction of the raven DjangoClient. It did not get passed any servers, and couldn't find sentry config to steal that config from.
I added in the settings.py:

```
SENTRY_SERVERS=<dnstoserver>
```

Console now outputs this every time raven is called:

```
INFO 2012-06-21 05:33:19,831 base 4323 140735075462336 Configuring Raven for host: <dnstoserver>
```

But it works like a charm! Messages in sentry...

BTW. for all the undocumented settings take a look in `raven.contrib.django.models.get_client()`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use:

```
SENTRY_DSN = 'http://user:password@<domain>:<port>/<project_id>'
```

And in APPS_INSTALLED add:

```
'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat'
```

Also take a look at this guide:
http://code.fetzig.at/post/18607051916/sentry-and-raven-setup-for-django-projects